# Slang word for procrastination?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, slang

Is there a slang word for "the art of doing useless things all day long" in English? I've been asked this today, and I the only word I can think of is "procrastination" but that's not slang. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps the informal phrases 'kicking the can down the road' or 'dilly-dallying' are used in a manner meaning procrastination.

Comment: Bumming around.

Comment: *Slacker* would be my first choice...

Comment: I would not say that "procrastination" is equivalent to "the art of doing useless things all day long"; if you want a single word, do you want it to fit "procrastination" or the thing you were asked about?

Comment: I know the perfect term, but it would take too long to explain right now, so I'll tell you later.

Comment: @Epistemonaut - "Kicking the can down the road" had a specific connotation that may not be appropriate.

Comment: @1006a - I need one word for the thing I was asked about. Indeed, procrastination does not fit here well, that was just the only word which came to my mind. In Russian we don't have a single word for "doing useless things all day long". Moreover, the person who asked this added that the word was ending with -ing and sounded like "pfuffing" or "pluffing". I still have no idea what it can be.

Comment: Ah, my guess in that case would be ***pottering/puttering*** (they're basically the same thing; the -o- spelling is more common in British English, and the -u- spelling is more common in American English).

Answer (score 0):

If it's chronic procrastination, you can refer to it as **procrastinationitis** (also spelled with a hyphen: procrastination-itis), which is obviously a combination of "procrastination" and "-itis", where "-itis" has this definition:

> *Informal* Used with reference to a tendency or state of mind that is compared to a disease.
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/-itis)</sub>

Here's an example of the word in action:

> I’ve come to the conclusion that I suffer from procrastination*itis*. It’s like, the minute I sit down to work, suddenly I *must* check my emails, then Facebook, then that article on writersdigest.com, then that blog I just started following, and next thing you know, I’m on Youtube watching a random video of three adorable poodles getting scolded for making a “mess”.
>   <sub>[Procrastinationitis: I Have it](http://www.biancascardoni.com/procrastinationitis-i-have-it/)</sub>

There are also quite a few Tweets that use [#procrastinationitis](https://twitter.com/hashtag/procrastinationitis?src=hash).